# Draw an image through desktop in java

Tags: java

How to draw an image using java in a window though its transparent part show what lying behind that window like desktop ,for instance ?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @pacman ,I want to make an application in java ,but i don't want it have the same interface of the JFrame rectangular shape , I want it to have a different interface I designed maybe specific shape image with certain buttons ,like a skin in any other program . I hope this express what I want , sorry for any misleading . Thanks in advance .

Comment: No Problem. Your chances of finding answers increases with understandable question. Also make sure to accept an answer if it helps you. This will increase your acceptance percentage and other users will be more willing to help you.

Take a look at the following link on how to ask clear questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is transparent windows.  Create a transparent window and put your images in the window.  Your images can have transparent sections.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/